# Cloning and detecting modifications on a document library on Sharepoint to be copyied on a OneDrive folder

Tags: power-automate, onedrive, modified

I'm new to SharePoint, and was wondering if there is a way to clone and detect changes into the folders stored in a document library in a SharePoint site to later be copied and/or modified into an specific folder in OneDrive, using Power Automate

I work for a Law firm and we keep all the clients folders containing all their data on SharePoint, we will start using an specific software for law firms and it has a OneDrive sync addin for us to "plug it" and work within an specific folder from OneDrive.

The folder is created automatically by the addin and it only works with this folder... meaning all the information that is "outside" wont be visible.

If somebody has experience and can share it, it would be much appricieated

best regards

Answer (score 1):

I would describe the rough actions you need in Power Automate.

1. You could start with a trigger named "[When a file is created or modified in a folder (properties only)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/business-apps/power-automate/sharepoint-connector-actions-triggers#when-a-file-is-created-or-modified-in-a-folder-properties-only)"
2. Then you can proceed with "[Copy file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/business-apps/power-automate/sharepoint-connector-actions-triggers#copy-file)" action by specifying the destination and the folder.

If you're new to Power Automate, there's number of learning resources from Microsoft such as this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/training/modules/get-started-flows/

Hope it helps.